# FTP transfer fails unless I open an ssh session with the server

Tags: centos, vsftpd

This is a strange issue.

I have a centOS 7 based server with vsftpd running as the FTP server.

If I use filezilla to copy a file from the centOS box to my local client the transfer fails after transfering a few MB about 128MB sometime less.

If I then SSH onto the CentOS server and log in, then attempt to repeat the FTP download doing exactly as before using filezilla the file transfers completely and quickly.

I cant for the life of me figure out why connecting to the server via SSH impacts the FTP transfer, can anyone think of any reason for this behaviour?

Comment: Could you simply transfer using one of the protocols that sit on top of `ssh`? You'll find that FileZilla will still handle that directly

Comment: Its 2023. Why are you still using FTP?

Comment: @symcbean because I have to.

Comment: Turns out I get the same effect with SCP and when transferring files using samba. It's actually the most bazar thing.

Answer (score 2):

If your FTP transfer only works when you open an SSH session with the server, it might be due to a few reasons:

1. Firewall or Security Settings: Your server's firewall or security settings may allow SSH connections but not FTP. You should check your server's configuration to ensure that FTP traffic is permitted.
2. [Port Forwarding](https://mistersempak.blogspot.com): FTP uses different ports for data and control connections. If your server is behind a NAT router, you might need to set up port forwarding to allow FTP connections.
3. Passive FTP: If you're using passive FTP, you might need to configure your FTP client to use a specific range of ports. Check your server's passive FTP settings and make sure your client is set up accordingly.
4. Server Configuration: The FTP server on your machine may have specific configuration settings that are causing issues. Review the FTP server's settings and logs to identify any potential problems.
5. User Permissions: Make sure the user account you are using for FTP has the necessary permissions to access and transfer files. SSH sessions might grant different permissions by default.

It's essential to check these aspects to determine why FTP transfers are failing without an open SSH session and to adjust your server or client configurations accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, a firewall is dropping your connection because of inactivity.

During a file transfer, your FTP client does not need to send anything to the server. Of course, TCP ACKs are sent by your client for each chunk of data received, but the problem is that FTP uses two channels, one for the data and one for the commands. The latter will remain silent for the duration of the transfer.

So, if the file is very big, its transfer will take a long time and an overzealous (and dumb) firewall may decide that the command channel is dead, will "close" it (possibly not in an orthodox way = sometimes by just stopping NAT-ing it, without making any side being aware of it), thus preventing the data transfer to eventually complete.

The solution? Use keep-alives. Either TCP keep-alives or application-layer keep-alives (no-op commands).

I see that FileZilla has a keep-alive option in **Settings->Connection->FTP->Send FTP keep-alive commands**. Just give it a try (however I don't see any setting regarding its frequency and it might turn out to be too short).

As to why an ssh connection prevents the connection from being dropped, this is kind of a mystery and you should ask the one that drops the connection in the first place (i.e. on what criteria?).

Finally, as suggested by Chris Davies's comment: using scp, sftp, ssh+tar or ssh+rsync would probably save you from those head-aches, as they use only one channel and integrate a flexible keep-alive mechanism.